# Is Williams's This Is Just to Say an imagist poem, an objectivist poem or neither?

Tags: poetry, style, william-carlos-williams

The Wikipedia article about the short poem ["This Is Just to Say"](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=This_Is_Just_to_Say&oldid=946494770) claims the text is an imagist poem without backing up that claim.
Williams contributed to the anthology [*Des Imagistes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Des_Imagistes), published in 1914.

By the time he published *Spring and All* in 1923, "Williams, like his peer and friend Ezra Pound, had already rejected the Imagist movement" ([William Carlos Williams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Carlos_Williams#Poetry) on Wikipedia).
"This Is Just to Say" dates from 1934, which is even later, and much closer in time to
[objectivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objectivism_(poetry)), which emerged in the 1930s.

This leads to the question whether "This Is Just to Say" is an imagist poem, an objectivist poem or something wholly independent of these movements.
If it belongs to either of the two aforementioned movements, why is this?